# Is it possible to change the TeX hyphenation rules for Ecclesiastical Latin?

Tags: hyphenation, latin

I am in the middle of a very large project using LaTeX (which means it would not be OK to switch to [XeTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX) or [LuaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LuaTeX)), and I'm starting to run into issues with hyphenation. The entire thing (some 3,000 pages) is written in [Ecclesiastical Latin](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Ecclesiastical_Latin#Proper_noun). I understand that I can make a list of words that are correctly separated with

```
\hyphenation{man-su-et\'udi-nim}
```

and making that list as long as it needs to be. Is there a better way to get the "right" rules into the document (since the rules for Ecclesiastical Latin—especially when sung—are different than English), or is this the best way—effectively inserting them into the hyphenation list one at a time as they come up?

Comment: /usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-var/tex/generic/config/language.dat has patterns for `classiclatin` , `latin` and `liturgicallatin` which you could select with babel

Comment: *mansuetudinim*? Are you sure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If I load `ecclesiasticlatin` for `babel`, the hyphenation points seem correct. Don't forget `T1` if you use `pdflatex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ecclesiasticlatin]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{
  \hspace{0pt}% to allow hyphenation of the first word
  mansuetudinem
  mansuetùdinem
  mansuetúdinem
  mansuetùdinim
  mansuetúdinim
}

\end{document}
```

I added *mansuetudinem* which seems more Latin to me.

[image]

Of course you can add other languages and use the standard `babel` methods to switch between languages. For instance

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ecclesiasticlatin,main=english]{babel}

\begin{document}

\parbox{0pt}{
  \hspace{0pt}% to allow hyphenation of the first word
  mansuetudinem % this uses English
  \foreignlanguage{ecclesiasticlatin}{mansuetudinem} % this uses Latin
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

see `texdoc babel-latin`  A starting point for setting up hyphenation  would be something like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[ecclesiasticlatin.ecclesiasticfootnotes,activeacute]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=liturgicallatin]{ecclesiasticlatin}


\showhyphens{mansuetúdinim}

\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

which with lualatex gives `man-sue-tú-di-nim` which isn't the breakpoints you showed, you could still of course provide exceptions via `\hyphenation` or better the language-aware `\babelhyphenation` but these should be much closer to what you need than the default English patterns, if that is what you are using.